# Adding sys/ioctl.ph to Perl headers

Tags: perl, ioctl

I need to use sys/ioctl.ph and it's not included in the perl version (5.12.3) shipped with my slackware distribution.

I did the following:

```
cd /usr/include
h2ph sys/ioctl.ph
cd /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/
mkdir sys
mv ioctl.ph sys
```

Now the perl interpreter doesn't complain about the sys/ioctl.ph, but this is the error I get:

`Illegal declaration of subroutine Functions::ServerSocket::__INT16_C at /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/_h2ph_pre.ph line 164.`

This is what there's in the file that causes the error at line 164:

`unless (defined &__INT16_C(c)) { sub __INT16_C(c)() { &c } }`

I don't know where to start. Functions::ServerSocket is one of my module, but I don't have any function like that in my file.

Answer (score 0):

The `__INT16_C` macro on your platform is probably simple, *e.g.*,

```
#define __INT16_C(c) c
```

Replace the code on line 164 with

```
eval 'sub __INT16_C {
    my($c) = @_;
    eval q($c);
}' unless defined (&__INT16_C);
```

which is what other versions of `h2ph` generate.